# Moving to the next column

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody please help me figure out my problem?
I have this code that I would like to move to the next column if the condition is not met.I'm stuck and don't know where to proceed.

```
Dim lrow3, lrow1 as long
dim dDate as Date
dim yrNum, j as Integer

dDate = Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")

lrow3 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lrow1 = Sheets("Sample").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
for j = 2 to lrow1
For yrNum = 1 To 100
    If DateValue(Format(Range("Q" & j).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) >= DateValue(dDate) And _
    DateValue(Format(Range("R" & j).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) <= DateValue(dDate) Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("D" & lrow3 + 1).Value = Range("T" & j).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E" & lrow3 + 1).Value = Range("U" & j).Value
    Exit For
    Else
         Range("Q" & j) = ActiveCell
         Range("Q" & j) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9)
    'after executing this is I have to set this offsetted cell to be the active one 
     'on which i will be referring in the next loop
    End If

Next yrNum
next j
```

In the snippet, if the value in `Q & j` does not met the requirements, then i have to check the 9th letter after Q which is Z and so on.
By the way what I'm comparing on this are date values in the cell.

Comment: Can you share entire code. I don't see your looping variable used any anywhere in the loop. Also what are the values of other variables j,lrow3..etc.I feel it will be good for others if you can share a bit more or full code

Comment: @Siva Updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for updating. What is the J value n your code. Are you iterating through rows are colums in this for loop?

Comment: j is used in looping the values in the sample sheet in column b.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to activate the cell 9 columns to the right of the ActiveCell .  This will accomplish that `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Activate`.  You are also trying to loop 900 columns over.  What is the starting address for the ActiveCell?

Comment: @ThomasInzina Its `Range("Q" & j).Select`.

Comment: @ramj You should watch all the VBA WiseOwlTutorials on Youtube.  [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)  is the relevant one.

Comment: @ramj: It's still not clear, what your question is. Do you get any errors? Where exactly are you stuck. Please specify what you really need to know. And: I personally would not work with `ActiveCell` and `Offset`, it's really slow and if you loop through a hundred columns, it'll probably take a while.

Comment: @ramj You should also watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 6 - Worksheets, Charts and Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3OE7Z62oGM&index=6&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations

- `dDate = Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")` is the same as `dDate = Date`
- `DateValue(Format(Range("Q" & j).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) is the same as`DateValue(Range("Q" & j).Value)`
- You are starting in column Q and if the conditions are not meet you move over 9 columns and check again.  You do this 100 times.  The final column is column 917(column letter code AIG)

---

```
Sub RefactoredCode()

    Dim lrow3, lrow1 As Long
    Dim DateRange As Range
    Dim wsSample As Worksheet
    Dim yrNum, j As Integer, iOffset As Integer

    Set wsSample = Worksheets("Sample")

    lrow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lrow1 = wsSample.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To lrow1
        For yrNum = 1 To 100

            iOffset = (yrNum * 9) - 9
            Set DateRange = wsSample.Cells(j, "Q").Offset(0, iOffset)

            If DateValue(DateRange.Value) >= Date And _
               DateValue(DateRange.Offset(0, 1).Value) <= Date Then
                lrow3 = lrow3 + 1
                Range("D" & lrow3).Value = wsSample.Cells(j, "T").Offset(0, iOffset).Value
                Range("E" & lrow3).Value = wsSample.Cells(j, "U").Offset(0, iOffset).Value
                Exit For
            End If

        Next yrNum
    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: The line `DateRange = wsSample.Cells(j, "Q").Offset(0, iOffset)` needs to be set. Thanks.